# Confusion about summation notation?

Tags: calculus, summation

having a bit of trouble working through sigma notation in first year calc. I get the basic principles at work here, but when the stopping point is a variable, like n, I don't really know how to simplify. Couldn't find answers elsewhere because I didn't quite know how to articulate my question!

So this is the question I'm working with, says to find the value of the sum.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (3 + 6i)^2$$

How would I evaluate this and then notate my answer?
Cheers!

Comment: Do you know formulas for a) $1+2+\cdots+n$, and b) $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2$?

Comment: Yep, I know that much. It's really more a question of applying them together here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer is in terms of $n$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (3+6i)^2 &=\sum_{i=1}^n(3^2+2(3)(6i)+(6i)^2) \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(9+36i+36i^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n 9 + 36\sum_{i=1}^n i + 36 \sum_{i=1}^ni^2
\end{align}

I hope you can evaluate the last expression.

Alternative:

\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^n (3+6i)^2&=9\sum_{i=1}^n(1+2i)^2 \\
&= 9 \left( -1+\sum_{i=0}^n(1+2i)^2\right)\\
&=9\left( -1 + \sum_{i=1}^{2n+1} i^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n(2i)^2\right)\end{align}